# Google Cloud Functions reports INVALID_ARGUMENT when uploading a zipped library

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I zipped up my `.py` files and `requirements.txt` and uploaded them to a Google Cloud Function. The only error reported in the Stackdriver logs for the deployment was `INVALID_ARGUMENT`.

Answer (score 0):

If your zip file is missing one of the `.py` files required by your cloud function, then you'll get the `INVALID_ARGUMENT` error.

Everything worked fine when I made sure the zip had everything in it.